# CentOS Application Installer Updates failed "Cannot resolve hostname"

Tags: centos, gnome, hostname, software-updates

I attempted to run updates from the `Application Installer` and ran into the following error.

```
failed to download https://extensions.ognome.org//extension-query/?shell_version=3.22.3&page=1&n_per_page=1000:
Cannot resolve hostname
```

I successfully ran `# yum update` prior to that and a second time yielded no updates. I also opened up a browser and had no problems browsing to a site.

If I read the problem correctly, CentOS cannot find extensions.gnome.org.

Here is a screenshot.

[image: CentOS Application Installer Update Failed]

Answer (score 1):

correct "extensions.ognome.org//" with "extensions.gnome.org/"

Comment: As I did not specify "//" in any way, I would not know where to make that change or if it is safe or what caused "//" in the first place. The "//" is 100%, make that 1000% percent, a result of the CentOS developer community and releasing buggy software. Please advise on the procedure and why making the change will be safe.

Comment: for the link "https://extensions.ognome.org//extension-query/" the browser says - the server was not found. for "https://extensions.gnome.org/extension-query/" - the correct answer. try yourself to enter into any browser

Comment: Repository description files are located in /etc/yum.repos.d/ and have a .repo extension. Find the correct one and correct it with any text editor.